# How to study def-thm-proof math books

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am currently studying intro to analytical number theory by Tom Apostol. It is a very def-thm-proof kind of textbook, and even after taking notes of definitions and theorems, i still struggle with exercises. Can someone please suggest a method for me to get more out of the book? Also, does anyone have lecture notes that can be paired with the book?

Comment: I advise spending between 45-90 minutes on a specific exercise.  Then, if you have not solved it, post a question on MathSE.  Do not skip any exercises.  Also, pay attention to [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  If you plan in advance, the protocol article is very little trouble.  ...see next comment

Comment: For one thing, many of the requested details (e.g. your background) will be the same from question to question, so you can simply cut/paste that portion into the posted question.  For another, with respect to the *tools* mentioned in the article, you will have already done that, if you made a sincere attempt to attack the problem on your own.  So, *showing work* is simply a matter of organizing your thoughts as you conduct the initial attack, just in case you have to post the question.  Following this procedure, posting a high quality question should not take more than 30 **extra** minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It can be hard to read such books slowly enough to digest all the material.

Some questions to ask yourself:

Why is the definition as it is? What properties of the definition is the author using in the proof? How are those properties deployed? [The proof may give a model for some of the exercises] - it is sometimes good to go back and work (more) slowly through each step to fix it in your mind.

What does this theorem give me? How might I be able to use it? How is the author using it?

What is the pattern of thinking involved here? If you get that then a lot will click into place, but it can be hard to scope a new way of thinking at first.